# browse button missing from input file in IE8?

Tags: html, file-upload, internet-explorer-8

I've taken a [screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/67597909@N08/6183601784/) of my file input method for both IE 9 and 8. Why would IE not show the browse button?  the table sits inside a form like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h3>Upload Photo</h3></td>
    </tr>      
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="2"><input type="file" name="mapimage" id="mapimage"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="update_image" id="update_image"/>      </td> 
        <td><img id="loading" src="images/loading.gif" alt="working.." style="visibility: hidden;" /></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried adding a size attribute but it still isn't showing up.  Are there any work arounds for IE 8 and below or is this a known issue?

Comment: I too saw this problem in IETester, both for IE7 and IE8. Unfortunately, I can't confirm if it works outside IETester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have some css somewhere doing this I see no problem.  It works for me in IE8.

Comment: very strange...I tried it on another machine with IE 8 and it does look correct.  Sorry about the post.

Comment: were you using IE Tester? I am noticing this in IE8 when using IE Tester

Answer (score 6):

I saw this as well when I was testing in IE Tester. Asked someone who had a native version of IE8 and saw it looks fine. I believe it's just a bug in IE Tester.

Comment: I also noticed it in IE Tester.
A virtual machine with IE8 showed the upload field just fine.